# Invalid Object Name [dbo].[udfKnowGoldCount]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am making a user defined function every thing is fine. when I try to use my function, I get this error msg:

> Invalid Object Name [dbo].[udfKnowGoldCount].

```
USE [ahsitsindia_sunriseprod]
GO
-- count silver member for gold claim
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udfKnowGoldCount] (@uid BIGINT)

RETURNS BIGINT

BEGIN

return (select count(MemberClub) from [dbo].[UserMaster] where PlacementID=@uid and MemberClub='Silver')
END
```

Here is my query:

```
if((select dbo.udfKnowGoldCount(@TempPlacementID))=4) 
begin 

UPDATE [dbo].[UserMaster] SET [MemberClub]='Gold' WHERE [UserID]=@TempPlacementID 

end
```

Comment: Can you also show how you use it?

Comment: provide your query where u used this function

Comment: if((select dbo.udfKnowGoldCount(@TempPlacementID))=4)
 begin
  UPDATE [dbo].[UserMaster] SET [MemberClub]='Gold' WHERE [UserID]=@TempPlacementID
 end

Comment: @RajKumar I add your query to your question, so you can remove the comment and remeber to show your query in next time :)

Comment: Start with the simple stuff. Are you running the second query on the same database? `ahsitsindia_sunriseprod`

Comment: Yes  i am doing the same as you told just..

Comment: @RajKumar Refresh your database

Comment: Can you `DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[udfKnowGoldCount]` and `CREATE FUNCTION` again.

Comment: Okay let me do that and thanks for help it's really useful for me.